# Replace in a string by zeros in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, css-parsing

I have this regular expression:

```
/@import\s*;/g
```

What I'm trying to do is to replace all the occurrences of `@import "blablabla";` by zeros or whitespaces in a string.
I tried using the `replace()` method this way:

```
"@import 'file.css';".replace(/@import\s*;/g, "0");
```

But it doesn't work because it replaces each occurrence by one zero. For example, I wanna replace `@import 'file.css';` by `0000000000000000000`, and not by `0`. Not that `@import 'file.css';` can be `@import       'file.css';`. So, you can't know the length of the string.

Is there any fast way to do this?

Comment: `.replace(/@import\s*(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|\S+);/g, function (x) { return "0".repeat(x.length); } );`. Well, not sure what you really want to match here, so you may use the idea.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That was the perfect answer! Thanks! But what's the secret behind your RegEx?

Comment: No idea. I thought the problem was with the replacement. Here, the replacement is an anonymous callback method passed as the second argument to `replace` method where `x` is the matched string.

Comment: It doesn't work when I write `/@import\s*;/g`, but it works with `/@import\s*(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|\S+);/g`. Why?

Comment: `@import\s*;` matches `@import`, 0+ whitespaces, `;`. `(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|\S+)` matches `"`, 0+ chars other than `"` and then a `"`, or `'`, 0+ chars other than `'` and then a `'`, or 1+ non-whitespace chars.